# Cannot assign to a value if it's a let constant - ERROR

Tags: swift, variables, xcode7, let

Here is my code :

```
var firstNumber: Double
var secondNumber: Double
var result: Double

var delegate: ComputeDelegate!

init(delegate: ComputeDelegate){

    self.delegate = delegate

}

func add(result: Double) -> Double {

    result = firstNumber + secondNumber

    return result

}
```

Here is the exact error : Cannot assign to value: 'result' is a 'let' constant

Thanks in advance! - Rookie here... ;) -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set value to your InputValue which is read only. You should change your method like this:

```
func add() -> Double {

    return firstNumber + secondNumber

}
```

Comment: Ayway, if I'm doing this, it gives me another error : var delegate: ComputeDelegate!
    
    init(delegate: ComputeDelegate){
        
        self.delegate = delegate
    } --- HERE ---> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties (this is the error)